# Force controllers to Change their orientation in Either Portrait or Landscape

Tags: objective-c, ipad, cocoa-touch

I have following Controllers, (I have selected all types orientation modes in iPad)

Here is my iPad Storyboard layout

```
Custom NavigationController > Loading Ctrl > Main Controller.
```

My Custom Navigation Contains

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return [[self.viewControllers lastObject] shouldAutorotate];
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return [[self.viewControllers lastObject] supportedInterfaceOrientations];
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return [[self.viewControllers lastObject] preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation];
}
```

In my Loading Controller

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    if (UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad == UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM())
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;
    else
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

The supportedInterfaceOrientations gets called as usual and everything seems ok, But when I push my Main Controller using performSegue

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    if (UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad == UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM())
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;
    else
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

No more calls in MainController. Why is that?

Comment: this works for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22491786/force-landscape-viewcontroller-in-ios-7/22491787#22491787

Answer (score 3):

There is one trick.

Fetch the status bar from the Application and rotate it.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait animated:YES];
```

Create and display and dismiss an empty view controller modally.

```
UIViewController *mVC = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
[self presentModalViewController:mVC animated:NO];
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

Now your device shoud have been forced to rotate. You could now segue to a proper view controller or push one using the navigation controller.

Comment: This worked, however, it useses deprecated functions (present and dismiss)

Comment: Yes, they were depricated with iOS 6 and replaced by ´presentViewController:animated:completion:´ and ´dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:´ . I did not yet try whether they work alike. If you give it a try I'd appreciate your feedback.

Comment: It "sort of worked" meaning it didn't work in every case.  Still trying to tease the why out of my application however...

Answer (score 1):

```
- (BOOL) shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation{
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);//choose portrait or landscape
}
- (BOOL) shouldAutorotate{
return NO;
}
- (NSUInteger) supportedInterfaceOrientations{
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;//choose portrait or landscape, same as above
}
```

Comment: THNX!! Is the best solution!

Comment: @n00bProgrammer which method need to call in -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated