# Autolayout IOS 7 Storyboard Force Landscape or Portrait

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, autolayout

I have a single storyboard where a majority of the views should be in portrait mode but one should be in Landscape.  I've down a significant amount of searching but keep coming up a little blank.

My current implementation which isn't exactly seeming to work as I hoped consists of the following bits of code I've pieced together from this website:

I've made a **RotationalViewController** which extends from **UINavigationController**

```
#import "RotationControlledViewController.h"

@interface RotationControlledViewController ()

@end

@implementation RotationControlledViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return [[self.viewControllers lastObject] shouldAutorotate];
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return [[self.viewControllers lastObject] supportedInterfaceOrientations];
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    UIInterfaceOrientation ret =  [[self.viewControllers lastObject] preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation];
    return ret;
}

@end
```

And then I've made a **PortraitViewController**

```
#import "PortraitViewController.h"

@interface PortraitViewController ()

@end

@implementation PortraitViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

and a **LandscapeViewController**

```
#import "LandscapeViewController.h"

@interface LandscapeViewController ()

@end

@implementation LandscapeViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
return YES;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight | UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
}

@end
```

I have played around with changing some of the settings but to no avail.  My general plan of attack has been to make specific view controllers inherit from either LandscapeViewController or PortraitViewController if I want to lock them to a specific orientation.

Things seem to be working for portrait view ( i can lock controllers into portrait view) but I seem unable to load my 1 landscape view and have it a) auto rotate to landscape upon load, or b) rotate to landscape at all.

Any suggestions would be very appreciated.

Comment: maybe look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18957785/force-controllers-to-change-their-orientation-in-either-portrait-or-landscape?rq=1

Comment: That works (sort of).  I think I can tweak it to not crash however.  Thanks

Comment: Perhaps take a second to answer your own question with the solution you used for the benefit of the community :)

Comment: maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22491786/force-landscape-viewcontroller-in-ios-7/22491787#22491787

Answer (score 1):

Applying the solution presented in:
[Force controllers to Change their orientation in Either Portrait or Landscape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18957785/force-controllers-to-change-their-orientation-in-either-portrait-or-landscape?rq=1)

I was able to make things work.

In both my **PortraiteViewController** and **LandscapeViewControllers** I modified the viewDidLoad method to:

**PortraiteViewController:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait animated:YES];

    UIViewController *mVC = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    [self presentModalViewController:mVC animated:NO];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```

**LandscapeViewController:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft animated:YES];

    UIViewController *mVC = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    [self presentModalViewController:mVC animated:NO];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```

This solution MAY stop working after IOS7 because both **presentModalViewController** and **dismissModalViewController** are deprecated.

Comment: I'll take a look shortly.  Thanks.