# lock a view to launch initially in landscape (ONLY landscape) objective-C

Tags: objective-c, view, ios7, landscape

I want to initially launch one of the View controllers in JUST landscape mode, while the other views and the whole app can work in both portrait and landscape. How can I do it in iOS 7? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your whole app may supports all orientations but one view controller needs to be landscape only.

You can easily stop your landscape view controller to rotate from landscape to portrait but when the app is in portrait already then it is difficult to force the deivce to rotate as this contradicts the iPhone manufacturers priciple.

In fact, it is not really difficult when you know the trick. See my answer to this similar question. 
[Force controllers to Change their orientation in Either Portrait or Landscape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18957785/force-controllers-to-change-their-orientation-in-either-portrait-or-landscape/18958670#18958670)